# Enforce a Single DB Writer in Node + Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have denormalized some some of the data I store in MongoDB, for the sake of reducing read-times. This will need to be refreshed whenever I do a write-operation, to keep it consistent with the underlying data.

To avoid any race conditions, I want to spin this off into a background task which would be single threaded. In Java, I would simply throw Command objects onto a queue, and have a reader-thread process them one at a time. But in Node, whenever I do any kind of DB operation it will happen asynchronously, and therefore I'm left with the race condition issue.

Example of what I want to do:

**Application Thread**

1. Insert new "Bid"
2. Put a "BidPlaced" object onto queue

**Background Thread**

1. Pop "BidPlaced"
2. Find max(Price) from all bids. Update Auction.highestBid.

I'm still getting my head around Node's concurrency model (in case you couldn't tell!). How do I achieve something like this in Node.js.

Comment: I may not have understood the question well, however one way to execute things in certain order using node is to 'execute' the 'next' task within the callback of the previous task. So when the first asynchronous call finishes, its callback is called and you can trigger the next 'task' from within this callback. I believe another way is to use EvenEmitters. For instance when a 'bid is placed' you emit an event. Also you have to define a listener for this events to do the 'Update Auction.highestBid'. Events are queued automatically so you don't need to define an explicit queue

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application where I use a [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) to fork the background jobs so:

1. Insert new "Bid"
2. Put a "BidPlaced" object onto queue

then I would send the child process the next bid in the queue:

```
// Application Thread
var child = cp.fork('the background thread module');
child.send(nextBid);
```

On the background thread listen for the message:

```
// Background Thread
process.on('message', function(bid) {
    // Do your background work
    process.send(bid);
});
```

Then listen for background completion in the application:

```
// Application Thread
child.on('message', function(lastBid) {
    // Check the queue and do it again
});
```